# Make post preview the same width as the post

Tags: feature-request, design

I try desperately to avoid orphans in my posts. Something like this really bugs me:

[image: post preview snippet]

The word "Rules" gets a whole line to itself. *I can't stand it*. I fiddle with it for a few minutes and then I decide that it isn't worth sacrificing clarity to make it perfect. I submit the post, and suddenly I see:

[image: actual post snippet]

Where'd my orphan go?

The screenshot is of the post preview window. The second is of the [actual post](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/23968/6692). They are not the same. I dug around a little in the CSS and found the culprit:

[image: css item]

The padding on the sides of the post preview window cause it to be 20 pixels smaller (less wide) than the post. Remove the padding, and the post preview looks exactly like the post on the page.

This seems like a no brainer to me. Remove the padding.

Comment: In the [actual post](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/23968/6692) you link, the preview of the answer is exactly the same as the actual post. I'm unable to reproduce this bug.

Comment: @Mhmd Can you take a screenshot to demonstrate? What browser are you using? Is anyone else able or unable to reproduce?

Comment: Here are expanded screenshots. [In edit mode.](http://i.imgur.com/mhlTZsL.png) [Out of edit mode.](http://i.imgur.com/jb8yq5E.png)

Comment: Here is the [actual post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X4CJU.png) and the [preview](http://i.stack.imgur.com/p6ey6.png). I'm using firefox developer edition 39.0a2

Comment: @Mhmd Look closely at your two screenshots. In the paragraph directly under **Regular REL**, one screenshot shows three lines of text, while the other shows two lines. The padding is affecting Firefox differently, but it is still affecting it.